# Is connectedness an intrinsic property of a set?

Tags: real-analysis

My undergraduate real analysis class is talking about set connectedness and has already discussed the fact that a set $E\subset X\subset Y$ is compact in $X$ iff it is compact in $Y$. Is the same true for connectedness? Is connectedness an intrinsic property of a set?

Comment: Try showing that if $E$ is not connected in $Y$, then it must be not connected in $X$.

Comment: Presumably you are using the subspace topology on $X$.

Comment: Just for fun, I'll stress that we really need $E \subset X$ here. For example, $(0,1)$ is not compact in $\mathbb{R}$, but it is compact in (the relative topology on) $\{ 1/2 \}$. While a lazy person might try to say "compactness is hereditary", it isn't quite true. (Not that you have made such a claim. I'm just musing out loud.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mean that compactness/connectedness is an intrinsic property of the **topology**.

And yes, this is true. The way to show this depends on what definition of connected you're using. For example, any continuous function to  a discrete space being constant characterizes connected spaces. Using this definition, we don't refer to ambient spaces at all, so the property must be intrinsic.